# MYSQL refuses to let me execute .sql script

Tags: mysql

I get the following error:

```
> ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 22: Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

[This](http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/f3/access-denied-user-root-localhost-using-password-yes-31551/) seemed like a noteworthy fix, however it yielded little results for me. I'm running ubuntu 10.04, and if the last thing I did which could have potentially disrupted it is reinstall apache, though if I recall correctly I hadn't touched mysql. I'm able to create schemas manually, I just can't (to the extent of my knowledge) execute .sql scripts. I've tried this both using a GUI client (MySQL Workbench) and via the command line.

Is this common? I've seen similar situations around Google, but most of this is either stuff that hasn't quite been relevant, or is bugs from MySQL releases which existed < 2006.

Comment: Can you post the command line you are using, and the first couple of lines of your script?

Answer (score 0):

Why does the script need to access `information_schema`? It's extremely rare to have to do anything to that unless you are installing mysql.

Perhaps the root user is blocked from accessing that. What is the exact command on line 22?

If nothing else, try executing the script manually one line at a time till you get the error line, then post it.

Answer (score 0):

Done. All I had to do was comment out the line which dealt with `information_schema` and everything worked.

Note: this was for a Joomla database, which could have been why `information_schema` was involved.